# How can I style a toggle to include a tick and cross?

Tags: html, css, toggle

I have a standard toggle switch, which I would like to style to resemble below using CSS only.

[image]

I have seen the following example, which achieves the effect:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
<div>
  <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  transition: 400ms all ease-in-out 50ms;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

/* Toggle State is :CHECKED */

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div {
  background: rgba(0, 122, 122, 1); /* Teal bg */

}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div label {
  left: 18px;
}

/* Shared */

div,
label {
  border-radius: 9999px;
}

/* Toggle State is 'un':checked */

div {
  height: 26px;
  width: 42px;
  background: rgba(224, 224, 224, 1); /* grey bg */
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50vh - 50px);
  left: calc(50vw - 100px);
  
}

label {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); /* white knob */
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
 
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  height: 15.5px;
  width: 1px; /* stroke */
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

label::after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px; /* stroke */
  width: 15.5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 0.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

label::before,
label::after{
  background: rgba(97, 97, 97, 1);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* pesduo class on toggle */

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div label::before{
  height: 12.5px;
  top: calc(55% - 6.5px);
  left: calc(60% - 1px);
  background: rgba(37,127,57,1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div label::after{
  width: 6px;
  top: calc(95% - 7.5px);
  left: calc(22.5% - 1.5px);
  background: rgba(37,127,57,1);
}
```

https://codepen.io/nuxpr/pen/YzabjeB

However this will not work for me since my HTML is different and cannot be changed. Here is my HTML.

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-tgl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-group-id-Targt"> 
  <label class="my-switch" for="my-group-id-Targt">
    <span class="my-switch-nob" role="switch"></span>
  </label> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There we go, just replacing div with label and label with span. (Also making the label and the span `display:block`). That did the trick. You can prefix all with your `div.class` if you want to namespace this.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  transition: 400ms all ease-in-out 50ms;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}


/* Toggle State is :CHECKED */

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
  background: rgba(0, 122, 122, 1);
  /* Teal bg */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14) 0 1px 3px 0 
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label span {
  left: 18px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}


/* Shared */

label,
span {
  border-radius: 9999px;
}


/* Toggle State is 'un':checked */

label {
  height: 26px;
  width: 42px;
  background: rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
  /* grey bg */
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50vh - 50px);
  left: calc(50vw - 100px);
  display:block;

}

span {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  /* white knob */
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14) 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

span::before {
  content: '';
  height: 15.5px;
  width: 1px;
  /* stroke */
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

span::after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  /* stroke */
  width: 15.5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 0.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

span::before,
span::after {
  background: rgba(97, 97, 97, 1);
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/* pesduo class on toggle */

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label span::before {
  height: 12.5px;
  top: calc(55% - 6.5px);
  left: calc(60% - 1px);
  background: rgba(37, 127, 57, 1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label span::after {
  width: 6px;
  top: calc(95% - 7.5px);
  left: calc(22.5% - 1.5px);
  background: rgba(37, 127, 57, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-tgl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-group-id-Targt"> 
  <label class="my-switch" for="my-group-id-Targt">
    <span class="my-switch-nob" role="switch"></span>
  </label> 
</div>
```